# Modify JavaScript to use ASCII character or image instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV that expands or collapses when clicked.  There is a + sign to indicates it expands, which changes to a - sign to indicate you can collapse it. Instead of the + and - sign, I want to use up and down arrows.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9PzRr/

I changed the .text to .html and plugged in the unicode values for the up/down arrows in place of the + and - symbols, but only the down arrow would show.  I'm open to using an image instead of the ASCII characters, but I am not familiar enough with Javascript/jQuery to know how to tell it to display an image instead of text.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expanderHead").click(function() {
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "\u25BC") {
            $("#expanderSign").html("\u25B2")
        }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("\u25BC")
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
    EXPANDING COLLAPSING DIV <span id="expanderSign">&#x25BC;</span>
    </h4>
    <div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
    </div>
    </body>
</html>    


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expanderHead").click(function() {
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "▼") {
            $("#expanderSign").html("▲")
        }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("▼")
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/9PzRr/1/

Or you can write the following in javascript code

```
 String.fromCharCode(0x25BC)
 String.fromCharCode(0x25B2)
```

It is recommended to use CSS background styles and toggle it for getting this.

Comment: Thanks! The code in the fiddle seems to be a good solution.  I'm trying to learn JavaScript; how would I incorporate the string.fromCharCode into what I already have?

Comment: $("#expanderSign").text(String.fromCharCode(0x25BC))